# Horizontal menu with overflow-x:auto

Tags: menu, overflow, css

Is it possible to have a horizontal menu that can scroll overflowed menuitems horizontally, but also display the vertical overflow when a submenu is to appear?

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are CSS3 properties and are not widely supported yet. See [this page](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html) for a demo in your browser.

edit: I checked the page in IE8 (and IE7 compat mode) and the "auto" examples all worked as they should. So it looks like the answer is "Yes".

Comment: They *are* in fact widely supported, even in IE, though not necessarily according to spec.